# Select a specific option based on the option group in selenium

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

hopefully this will not be an duplicate. I searched in web but could not find the exact solution for what i need. I have a dropdown with option groups. I need to select a value based on the input option group "Primary Borrower" or "Co-Borrower" from the dropdown and proceed. Could you please help me on how to do that.

[image: dropdown]

here is the angular code.

```
<select name="selected-borrower" id="selected-borrower" data-ng-model="BorrowerCtrl.selected" data-ng-options="borrower.getFullName() group by borrower.getGroup() for borrower in BorrowerCtrl.borrowers | borrowerSort" data-ng-disabled="BorrowerCtrl.selected.updateInProgress" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" aria-invalid="false" style="">
  <optgroup label="Primary Borrower">
    <option label="CLAUDINE G SELSER" value="object:1426" selected="selected">Person One</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Co-Borrower">
    <option label="LEOTA N MACHUCA" value="object:1427">Person Two</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPaths are the solution.

```
WebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='selected-borrower']/optgroup[@label='Primary Borrower']/option")).click();
```

In plain English, this XPath traverses from the select element with the id 'selected-borrower' to the optgroup with the label 'Primary Borrower' and selects the first option (which in this case is the option labeled 'CLAUDINE G SELSER'). You could modfiy the `@label=` portion to work for the co-borrowers if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Dean. This made the things work. I navigated upto the 'option', but did not get the click idea on that and now i got it from your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Select class like the one below:

```
 Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selected-borrower")));
 select.selectByVisibleText("CLAUDINE G SELSER");
```